# TypeORMError: Connection is not established with mysql database from CLI Script

Tags: mysql, typeorm

I am using TypeORM with nestJS.
I have a cli script which is executed as command using nest-commander.
In the script, I have couple of SQL queries. I noticed that it only executes the first query. For the next query I get the error `TypeORMError: Connection is not established with mysql database`
The same script gets executed correctly with NestJS cron.

Any one has any idea why this error from CLI ?

1. From NestJS cron everything works fine.
2. From CLI it only executes the first query. For the next query it shows the error. \
3. I am using Repository Pattern.
4. Tried to change the query with `queryRunner.manager`
5. If I enclose multiple queries into a transaction with queryRunner.manager it works. But in my Case it is not possible to put all into one transaction. Multiple transactions also does not work.